# Display 24h time in Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011, office-for-mac

How do I display 24h time in Outlook 2011 for Mac?

I´ve looked around in all menus but can´t seem to find out where I can set this. I can live with AM/PM, but 24h would work better for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have experience with Macs, but on Windows [it's tied to the system settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/switch-calendar-views-between-a-12-hour-clock-and-24-hour-clock-HA001230298.aspx).

> Microsoft Outlook uses the country/region settings for your computer to determine how the times appear.
>
> For example, in Calendar in the month view, if you are using the default settings for the United States, Outlook displays a 12-hour clock. After 12:59 P.M., the time is displayed as 1 P.M. Other countries/regions use a 24-hour clock.
>
> You can change how the clock appears in your display. However, changing this display is an option provided by the operating system, not Outlook.

Comment: I managed to find some settings in OSX and last, and now it works. The machine was displaying a 24h clock already, but I had to change the default language settings for my region.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 4):

Yes Outlook will use the country settings as specified in system preferences. However - you can change this in settings Language & Region  settings once for this to take effect in Outlook 2011 / 2016 / Office 365. So quit Outlook, go to:

- system preferences
- Language & Region
- and check the time Format: 24-Hour Time

Exit when it is how you want it and restart Outlook. This is how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is a dated post, but others may find this useful.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click Language & Region
3. Check the box for 24-Hour time next to Time Format in your default language

This changes your system time format. Most people change their clock to display 24-Hour time, but that only affects the clock in the menu bar and not the system.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook should use the system settings from your computer.